# Updating XML Node Changes XML Formatting

Tags: xml, formatting, save

I am trying to update an XML document and replace the contents of a single node, however, after I save the XML file, my formatting goes all skew.

This is my code:

```
Public Sub UpdateSettingsXML(ByRef ElementName As String, ByRef ElementValue As String)
    Dim MyXML As New XmlDocument()
    Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode

    MyXML.Load(SettingsXMLFile)
    MyXMLNode = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("//Data/Settings/" & ElementName)
    If Not MyXMLNode Is Nothing Then
        MyXMLNode.InnerText = ElementValue.ToString
        MyXML.Save(SettingsXMLFile)
    End If

    MyXMLNode = Nothing
    MyXML = Nothing
End Sub
```

My original XML File (before I update the node) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Data>   
 <Settings>
    <DropBoxLocation></DropBoxLocation>
    <ServerName></ServerName>
    <DatabaseName></DatabaseName>
    <Username></Username>
    <Password></Password>
    <OnlineFilename></OnlineFilename>
    <OfflineFilename></OfflineFilename>
    <EftposFilename></EftposFilename>
    <BankFilename></BankFilename>
    <POSFilename></POSFilename>
    <ProcessesFilename></ProcessesFilename>
    <FileReadDelay></FileReadDelay>   
 </Settings> 
</Data>
```

However, once I save the XML file my formatting looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Data>   
 <Settings>
    <DropBoxLocation>C:\Dropbox</DropBoxLocation>
    <ServerName>
    </ServerName>
    <DatabaseName>
    </DatabaseName>
    <Username>
    </Username>
    <Password>
    </Password>
    <OnlineFilename>
    </OnlineFilename>
    <OfflineFilename>
    </OfflineFilename>
    <EftposFilename>
    </EftposFilename>
    <BankFilename>
    </BankFilename>
    <POSFilename>
    </POSFilename>
    <ProcessesFilename>
    </ProcessesFilename>
    <FileReadDelay>
    </FileReadDelay>   
 </Settings> 
</Data>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't seem to find any info on the web about this issue.  Wondering if someone could help my please.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you use the code below?
It uses the PRESERVEWHITE parameter

Does it fix your formatting?

```
Public Sub UpdateSettingsXML(ByRef ElementName As String, ByRef ElementValue As String)

  Dim MyXML As New XmlDocument()
  Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode

  'REM - THIS LINE ADDED
  MyXML.PreserveWhitespace = false

  MyXML.Load(SettingsXMLFile)
  MyXMLNode = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("//Data/Settings/" & ElementName)
  If Not MyXMLNode Is Nothing Then
    MyXMLNode.InnerText = ElementValue.ToString

    'REM - THIS LINE ADDED
    MyXML.PreserveWhitespace = false
    MyXML.Save(SettingsXMLFile)
  End If
  MyXMLNode = Nothing
  MyXML = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Trying your example didn't make any difference to the output, however, changing the value to true has achieved it.

'REM - THIS LINE ADDED
  MyXML.PreserveWhitespace = true


Thanks so much for your help and quick response.